# Speeding up page load time by delaying execution of directive link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Some of my directives' link function takes considerable time to execute. So it delays the page load time.

To make it faster, Intention is to execute the linkfn after window.onload event.

The approach that I am planning to take

```
directive('mydirective', function(){
  restrict: 'A',
  scope:{},
  link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var unwatcher = scope.$watch("$viewcontentloaded", function(){
       unwatcher();
      //actual link function which takes too much time to execute.
    });
  }
}
```

Btw, using $timeout(linkfn, 0) does not guarantee it to execute after window.onload event [more info](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/settimeout-onload).

Any other better option?

Answer (score 0):

checkout bindonce at https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce and also try to load your template html with **template:** instead of **templateUrl:** if you are not already